# Unable to save empty list to Django ArrayField

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Website(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta = ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True), default=list)
```

I'm using following serializer to save data to the DB:

```
class WebsiteConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = ('status', 'meta')
```

When I'm trying to save the following data, I'm getting error:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "meta": []
}

#ERROR:
# "meta : This list may not be empty."
```

Is it not possible to save an empty list to an `ArrayField` ?
When I'm not passing the field at all, the value getting stored is `{NULL}`.
Also during initial migrations, since I had added a `default` value as `list`, all my existing entries had "meta" value as `{}`

If the  empty list value is not allowed at all, how come this got saved during initial migration ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try chaging your model to

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Website(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta = ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True), default=list, blank=True)
```

Comment: Downvoted because a) don't fix a serializer problem in an otherwise sane model definition and b) you're doing exactly what the documentation tells you not to do (quoted in my answer).

Comment: you are correct about the list callable, but you do have to change the model, namely `blank=True`. I edited my answer to avoid misguiding people.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the `ModelSerializer` class.

Comment: blank=True works and is ModelSerializer related.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to save an empty list, it's even a possible default as [the documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield):

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as list (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a list (such as a function). Incorrectly using default=[] creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of ArrayField.

However, your serializer doesn't allow empty values:

```
class WebsiteConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meta = serializers.ListField(
        allow_empty=True,
        child=serializers.CharField(
            max_length=200, allow_blank=True
        )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = ('status', 'meta')
```

You can simplify this, by creating a serializer field:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ArrayField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)

class WebsiteConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meta = ArrayField(allow_empty=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = ('status', 'meta')
```

Comment: adding an empty list at different instances shouldn't cause any mutability related issues also. right ?

Comment: you don't need to define the serializer if the model is correctly defined. If you use `ModelSerializer` the mapping will be autogenerated. see: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e888fc11c76d1a671f6f7d3c080915ffe722f3f6/tests/test_model_serializer.py#L464